# Is the NO-VERTEX-COVER in NP or not?

Tags: algorithm, np

This is the reverse version of vertex cover problem. Consider a decision problem that asks whether, given a graph G = (V, E) and a nonnegative integer k, there does not exist a vertex cover of size no larger than k. Answer whether this problem is NP or not ? Please explain to me.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer would be no (unless [`co-NP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP)`=`[`NP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity))).

Your decision problem, `NO-VERTEX-COVER`, is exactly the complement of the well-known `VERTEX-COVER` problem; the latter problem is `NP`-complete (and is, of course, in `NP`). Your problem `NO-VERTEX-COVER` is thus in `co-NP`. (Recall that a problem is in `co-NP` if and only if its complement is in `NP`.)

Because `VERTEX-COVER`, the complement of you problem, is `NP`-complete, it follows that unless `co-NP=NP`, the `NO-VERTEX-COVER` problem is not in `NP`. (This follows from a theorem that says that if `co-NP` is not equal to `NP` then no `NP`-complete problem is in `co-NP`.)